# Solve these two multivariable equations simultaneously.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I solve the following system of equations? $$\begin{cases}3x^2 + y + 2xy^2 - 3&=0\\ x(1+2yx)&=0 \end{cases}$$

Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(1) 3x^2 + y + 2xy^2 - 3=0\\(2)x(1+2xy)=0\\multiply (1)-by-x\\3x^3 + yx + 2x^2y^2 - 3x=0\\3x^3-3x+y(x(1+2y))=0\overset{x(1+2xy)=0}{\rightarrow} \\3x(x^2-1)+y(0)=0\\3x(x^2-1)=0\\x=0,1,-1\\now\\x=0\overset{(1)}{\rightarrow}y-3=0\\x=1\overset{}{\rightarrow}y=\frac{-1}{2}\\x=-1\overset{}{\rightarrow}y=\frac{+1}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! Why have you multiplied the first equation and done nothing to the second?

Comment: when I get x put them into 2nd and find  y , so I use (2)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** 

$x(1+2yx)=0$ means that $x=0$ or $1+2yx=0$. Can you proceed further?

Comment: That means y=3, or I have to solve -y^3 + 0.75y^2 + y - 3=0. I am hving trouble solving that. However my solutions manual says x,y is (1, -1/2). I can't see how they arrived at that.

Comment: @Amaa You have three pairs of solutions, for $x=0$ you have $y=3$. And for the case $1+2yx=0$ you write $y$ in terms of $x$ then using the first equation you will have to find the value $x$, plug it in $1+2yx=0$ to finish it off.

Comment: Thanks I've spotte where I went wrong and have been able to solve it!